# Extracting data from one excel sheet to another

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a large excel file that looks like this:
[image]

And it then goes on all the way to F01. And then repeats itself again with A01,A02... and so on and on and on.

How can I create a new sheet that extracts all the data from only the wells named A01?
I thought about IF statements but do not really have any idea on how to succeed with it.

Comment: Consider using an ***AutoFilter.***

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into PowerQuery - Data --> Get Data --> From File

When the dialogue pops up - click on the Transform Data button.

[image: Button]

You can then filter the data and load it to a new spreadsheet.